# Run Http requests in certain order JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am implementing a user Http request Test plan in JMeter and the scenarios need to be run in a certain order because they are dependent, eg:

1. create user; (extract the user id with Json extractor)
2. create order for this user id (extract the order id with Json extractor)
3. ship order for this order id

Is there a way to run the scenarios making sure this dependency among the Http requests? So when having several Threads I will not face any issue like (shipping an order already shipped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JMeter executes requests **upside down** (if there are no [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) which may amend this behaviour) so there is nothing you need to do
2. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are local to the thread so you have the confidence that each ID will be unique for each JMeter thread (virtual user)

You may find [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) article useful as well

Comment: Hey, Adding a Simple Controller solved my issue. Thank you so much!